# How can I make Flex:1 for mobile devices responsive?

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, flexbox

I created 3 columns, each with the same exact width. I used the following code to create this:

My plan was to have 3 divs with 33.33% width each, and on mobile phones, each 'category' div should have 100%.

I tried it with `width: 33.33%`, but since I want a little bit of space in between the divs, 33.33% is too much width.

That's why I tried flex.

How can I make this version for mobile phones so that each category div has 100 width?

```css
.category-main-layout {
    width: 100%;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    margin: auto;
}
.category {
    flex: 1;
    text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="category-main-layout">
    <div class="category">
    CONTENT
    </div>
    <div class="category">
    CONTENT
    </div>
    <div class="category">
    CONTENT
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: `flex: 0 0 100%;` and a media query.

Comment: This makes my box 100%, but then the other two boxes are outside of the website.. How can I place the boxes underneath each box then? thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use media queries to achieve this. Here, if screen is larger than 500px, then categories will be displayed as block and so each is 100% width.

```css
.category-main-layout {
  width: 100%;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  margin: auto;
}

.category {
  flex-grow: 1;
  text-align: center;
  border: 1px red solid;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 500px) {
  .category-main-layout {
    display: block;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="category-main-layout">
  <div class="category">
    CONTENT
  </div>
  <div class="category">
    CONTENT
  </div>
  <div class="category">
    CONTENT
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

hey you can try this in flex way you need to change little bit in your code

see my fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/arindam1996/v4ya76th/3/

```css
.category-main-layout {
    width: 100%;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    justify-content: space-between;
    margin: auto;
}
.category {
    flex: 1;
    text-align: center;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 576px) {
  .category {
    -ms-flex: 0 0 100%;
    flex: 0 0 100%;
    max-width: 100%;
}
}
```

```html
<div class="category-main-layout">
    <div class="category">
    CONTENT
    </div>
    <div class="category">
    CONTENT
    </div>
    <div class="category">
    CONTENT
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for helping. This version somehow doesn't work here on Safari. But I already got an solution with display: block. Thanks for helping!!!

Comment: welcome. It will work on safari if you added corresponding hack for display flex and `flex-wrap` or try latest bootstrap 4.